# Python code making thousands of empty features in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Am a used to ArcPy and using that for my coding, however, I now have to use QGIS. So I want to be able to write a script that will take a polygon that I made and then duplicate said polygon two meters over and then do that however many times I want.

Here is an example of an end product would be

[image]

So the problem is that this code creates thousand of empty feature but also makes the polygons that I want it to make. How would you solve this?

```
from qgis.core import *

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\JBlankenship\Documents\Wilbur-Ellis\Drone Pics 2018\Iowa\7004-1824\June_5\Shapefile\7004_1824.shp", "7004_1824.shp", "ogr")


The_Features = layer.getFeatures()
times_x=0
times_y=0
num1=0
num2=0
num3=0




while num1 <= 7:
    print("Big loop",num1)
    num2=0
    num3=0
    x1=0
    x2=15.4+times_x

    y1=4.6
    y2=0


    for i in layer.getFeatures():
        geom = i.geometry()
        Polygon_cor = geom.asMultiPolygon()
        Point_1_x = Polygon_cor[0][0][0][0]
        Point_1_y = Polygon_cor[0][0][0][1]

        Point_2_x = Polygon_cor[0][0][1][0]
        Point_2_y = Polygon_cor[0][0][1][1]

        Point_3_x = Polygon_cor[0][0][2][0]
        Point_3_y = Polygon_cor[0][0][2][1]

        Point_4_x = Polygon_cor[0][0][3][0]
        Point_4_y = Polygon_cor[0][0][3][1]
        print("Reset")

        break
    print(num1) 
    if num1 > 0:
        while num3 < 1:
            num3+=1
            Point_1_x = Point_1_x + x2
            Point_1_y = Point_1_y + y2
            Point_2_x = Point_2_x + x2
            Point_2_y = Point_2_y + y2
            Point_3_x = Point_3_x + x2
            Point_3_y = Point_3_y + y2
            Point_4_x = Point_4_x + x2
            Point_4_y = Point_4_y + y2
            print("Done R",num3)
            times_x += 15.4


            # Set the provider to accept the data source
            prov = layer.dataProvider()
            points = [QgsPointXY(Point_1_x,Point_1_y), QgsPointXY(Point_2_x,Point_2_y), QgsPointXY(Point_3_x,Point_3_y), QgsPointXY(Point_4_x,Point_4_y)]

            # Add a new feature and assign the geometry
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [points]))
            prov.addFeatures([feat])

            # Update extent of the layer
            layer.updateExtents()





    while num2 < 7:
        num2+=1
        Point_1_x = Point_1_x + x1
        Point_1_y = Point_1_y + y1
        Point_2_x = Point_2_x + x1
        Point_2_y = Point_2_y + y1
        Point_3_x = Point_3_x + x1
        Point_3_y = Point_3_y + y1
        Point_4_x = Point_4_x + x1
        Point_4_y = Point_4_y + y1
        print("Done C",num2)

        times_y += 1

        # Set the provider to accept the data source
        prov = layer.dataProvider()
        points = [QgsPointXY(Point_1_x,Point_1_y), QgsPointXY(Point_2_x,Point_2_y), QgsPointXY(Point_3_x,Point_3_y), QgsPointXY(Point_4_x,Point_4_y)]

        # Add a new feature and assign the geometry
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [points]))
        prov.addFeatures([feat])

        # Update extent of the layer
        layer.updateExtents()



    num1+=1
```